# linux memory swappiness: why not always 0?

Tags: linux, paging

Linux allows the user to change the system swappiness from 0 to 100. If set to 0, the kernel will disable swapping and all processes will be maintained in memory if spared memory is available. Conversely, if set to 100, the kernel will swap aggressively. My question is, why not always setting the swappiness to 0? As a system user, we may always expect our programs to be maintained in memory rather than swapped to disk. So I think setting the swappiness to 100 is meaningless, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on [another stack exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88693/why-is-swappiness-set-to-60-by-default) having some swap is good. It frees up memory from processes that are rarely using it so that more active processes have access to RAM. A swappiness level of about 60 is a good balance as it frees up unused memory without hindering the performance of more active processes dramatically.

It all depends on how much RAM you have and will use.

Comment: +1. As a concrete example of that: a typical case for high swappiness is a multi-user terminal server. This allows the system to swap out the programs that users leave running when they disconnect, freeing memory for page caching and resulting in more responsive programs with quicker load times for active users.

Answer (score 0):

Setting swappiness to 100 is an extreme situation, for sure. But one may always think of a scenario where this could be necessary.

The other situation, setting swappiness to 0, seems to be that best thing to to, but it isn't. Just for start, what would happen if you had done this and a process needed more memory? A crash, probably.

Then, as @limecore said above, having some swap memory is always good.